# NavBar positioned bottom in mobile app

Tags: css

What I'm trying to do is have a navigation bar positioned on the bottom side of my mobile app, which doesn't move if i scroll the page. I've tried with this code but then i don't manage to handle the link elements, the written words doesn't allign to the center of the box in which they're contained:

```
ul{
  list-style:none;
  text-align:center;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(black,#404040);}
li{
  display:inline-block;
  height:40px;
}
li a {
  color:white; 
  font: bold 15px verdana;
  text-decoration:none;
  display:block;
  height:40px; }
```

The HTML is just two element (Home and Who we are).
How can I do? Thanks!
Edit: As you can see from the picture, there is the problem: the text is not alligned to the center [image]

Comment: How you don't manage? what is the issue? And what is your html?

Comment: You forgot to close the ul style, there is a "}" missing

Comment: Try adding padding: 10px 0; to the li element, is it that what you want? More informations like a fiddle would be better.

Comment: No, I would like some advices to create a nav bar which remains stuck at the bottom